# Play audio in background while built-in music player is active ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

Using the `AVAudioSession` class, it is possible to play audio in the background, but I was wondering if it is possible to play audio in the background and having the built-in music player playing at the same time. Based on the documentation, this seems to be impossible.

Is there a configuration that I am overlooking or a reliable workaround?

Comment: You can't. Because built-in player also uses the same way to play the music. The `AVAudioSession` is in use. Alternatively, you can play it in foreground, but it is not the question you are referring to.